# SQL Query with HAVING clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing a query which will return a recordset that returns a list of transactions that are > 2 years from the date the query is run.  The below query returns records that are within the 2 years.

```
select distinct(itemid) from bwc_trav_InHistSoldOrConsumed_view
group by itemid
having max(transdate)<dateadd(yyyy,-2,getdate())
```

Comment: What is the data type of `transdate`?  Can you provide some sample date that the query returns but shouldn't?

Comment: I added the sql-server tag because the syntax looks like SQL Server.

Comment: What is your question? Is it how to return records that are older than 2 years?

Comment: Datatype for transdate is datetime.

Comment: Yes, that is the question threeFourOneSixOneThree.  The above query is returning records that are within the last 2 years.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from
(
    select itemid, max(transdate) dt from bwc_trav_InHistSoldOrConsumed_view
    group by itemid
) t where t.dt < dateadd(year, -2, getdate())
```

Comment: Thanks.  This appears to work accurately...I am in the process of validating now.